# NestJs websockets UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, websocket, nestjs

I'm trying to add a 'events' module to my application for using websockets,
but when I add the module I get the following error:

```
(node:59905) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Request mapping properties not defined in the @RequestMapping() annotation!
(node:59905) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

All the other modules are loaded and mapped successfully and it only happens when I add the EventsModule

so here's the code that I have:

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
    modules: [AuthModule, DatabaseModule, UsersModule, TimespansModule, LogsModule, EntitiesModule, EventsModule]
})
```

events.module.ts

```
import {EventsComponent} from './events.component';
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
@Module({
    controllers: [EventsComponent]
})
export class EventsModule {}
```

events.component.ts

```
import {WebSocketGateway, SubscribeMessage, OnGatewayConnection} from '@nestjs/websockets';

@WebSocketGateway({namespace: 'events'})
export class EventsComponent implements OnGatewayConnection {
    handleConnection(client: any) {
        console.log('client connected');
    }

    @SubscribeMessage('stream-received')
    onStream(client, data) {
        console.log('stream received');
    }
}
```

I can't really see what's going wrong here, also the error message doesn't help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue in events.module.ts

```
import {EventsComponent} from './events.component';
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';    
@Module({
    controllers: [EventsComponent]
})
export class EventsModule {}
```

had to change controllers => components

```
import {EventsComponent} from './events.component';
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';    
@Module({
    components: [EventsComponent]
})
export class EventsModule {}
```